# Displaying info in a for loop from data in an array pulled from a json file

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I am trying to pull data from a json file then print it out in a script I have to create an image with information about server status.

Here is my json data in serverstatus.json

```
[{"load":"high"},{"load":"low"},{"load":"low"},{"load":"low"}]
```

Here is my script

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.shipsofwar.net/servers?apikey=hPANE457LsBGmCUCD8JtoX7df44T52rYHJ8Gu0ZU';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

$image = imagecreatefrompng('status.png');
imagealphablending($image, true);

$fontsize = 20;
$font = 'CaviarDreams';
$color1 = imagecolorallocate($image, 42, 8, 145); //blue
$color2 = imagecolorallocate($image, 30, 50, 98); //light blue
$server[0] = 'PvP One EU';
$server[1] = 'PvE One USA';
$server[2] = 'PvP Two USA';
$server[3] = 'PvP 3 EU mirror';
$ping[0] = '';
$ping[1] = '';
$ping[2] = '';
$ping[3] = '';
//imagefttext("Image", "Font Size", "Rotate Text", "Left Position", "Top Position", "Font Color", "Font Name", "Text To Print");

foreach($json['data'] as $item)
{
    //Determine the server status
    if($item['status'] == 'working')
    {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 7, 146, 44);//green
        $serverstatus = 'Online';
    }

    if($item['status'] == 'update')
    {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 242, 181, 77); //orange
        $serverstatus = 'Update';
    }

    if($item['status'] == 'maintenence')
    {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 30, 50, 98); //blue
        $serverstatus = 'Maintenence';
    }

    if($item['status'] != ('working' || 'update' || 'maintenence'))
    {
        $color = imagecoloralolcate($image, 244, 55, 66);//red
        $serverstatus = 'Offline';
    }
}

foreach($json['data'] as $item2)
{
    $load = $item2['load'];
    $values[] = array(
        'load' => $load,
    );
    file_put_contents('serverload.json', json_encode($values));
}

$json_file = file_get_contents("serverload.json");
$json_load = json_decode($json_file, true);

foreach ($json_load as $item3)
{
    $lat = $item3['load'];
    $latency[] = array(
        'load' => $lat,
    );

    $ping = $lat;
}

for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
{
    $name = $server[$i];
    imagefttext($image, $fontsize, 0, 20, (20*$i+30)+(20*$i), $color1, $font, $name);
    //if($item['status'] != ('update' || 'maintenence'))
    //{
        imagefttext($image, $fontsize, 0, 260, (20*$i+30)+(20*$i), $color2, $font, $ping[$i]);
    //}
    imagefttext($image, $fontsize, 0, 340, (20*$i+30)+(20*$i), $color, $font, $serverstatus);
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

The issue I am having is displaying the info from the serverstatus.json file. I think my issue is not fully understanding how to add information to the $ping array from $lat. The way I am trying to get it to display is like below.

```
PvP One EU        high   Online
PvE One USA       low   Online
PvP Two USA       low   Online
PvP 3 EU mirror   low   Online
```

But it is displaying like this instead.

```
PvP One EU        l   Online
PvE One USA       o   Online
PvP Two USA       w   Online
PvP 3 EU mirror       Online
```

I've been trying to understand this for a couple hours now and I have tried so many things but nothing seems to work right. I have been on stack for 3 hours now looking through every question similar to mine but have yet to find the answer or even a clue to the right answer. Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you just overwrite `$ping` variable with:

```
$ping = $lat;
```

But you should add `$lat` as an element of `$ping` array:

```
foreach ($json_load as $item3)
{
    $lat = $item3['load'];
    $latency[] = array(
        'load' => $lat,
    );

    $ping[] = $lat;    // here, add []
}
```